# Why I can't directly use result of webPage.create() in Phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am using phantomjs to create Base64 screenshots of pages. I have got something, I really don't quite understand. Here is my code:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');

var page = webPage.create();

page.open('http://example.com', function (status) {
  var base64 = page.renderBase64('PNG');
  console.log(base64);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

What I wonder is why I can't use result of webPage.create() immediately?

For instanse this code won't finish:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');

webPage.create().open('http://example.com', function (status) {
  var base64 = page.renderBase64('PNG');
  console.log(base64);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: The code won't finish because there is no `page` variable defined. **Igor**'s answer explains how to make the code work again.

Comment: @Annarfych I did not notice that it is self referencing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**By default, there is no object named `page`, so, you need to create it:**

```
var page = require('webpage').create({viewportSize:{width: 1600,height: 900},
settings:{userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
javascriptEnabled:'true',
loadImages:'true'
}});
```

After that, you can use it as usual, for example: `page.renderBase64('PNG');`

**Or you may use the pointer named `this` (a reference to the current object):**

```
require('webpage').create().open('http://example.com',function(status){
  var base64 = this.renderBase64('PNG');// You can use "this", instead of the object name.
  console.log(base64);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

**Or the same, but with an additional settings for the `create()` function:**

```
var obj={viewportSize:{width: 1600,height: 900},
settings:{userAgent:'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:49.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/49.0',
javascriptEnabled:'true',
loadImages:'true'
}}// The additional settings for the create() function.

require('webpage').create(obj).open('http://example.com',function(status){
  var base64 = this.renderBase64('PNG');// You can use "this", instead of the object name.
  console.log(base64);
  phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: but why webPage.create() does not return a page immediately?

Answer (score 1):

You need to [`open()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/open.html) page because simply calling `create()` only instantiates the page object so you can add some event handlers on it before the page was actually loaded. Because adding those callbacks after it's loaded and you have your content would defeat purpose of some of them. Like [`onLoadStarted`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-started.html) event for example.

Comment: But you see - I do open it, just don't create intermediate variable.

Comment: JavaScript engine creates it by itself when it executes the code up to 
`webPage.create()`. And in general when you chain functions with `.`. It's implicit.